# When to setImageBitmap during creation of Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

I need to setImageBitmap during creation of fragment. I cannot do this in `onCreate`, because `ImageView` is not initialized yet.
I had the same problem in Activity, but then I called `onWindowFocusChanged` method and it worked. But there is no such method in Fragment. How should I solve this? 
I tried also

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String imgPath = day.getPhotoPath();
    if (imgPath != null) {
        dayPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, imgPath));
    }
}
```

but this also gives no results. The fragment is blank

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    dayPhoto = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dayImage);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your onCreateView() code ? You also need to double check result decodeSampledBitmapFromFile() if it is not null.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The method is fine. As I wrote above, I had similiar problem in Activity, so here also, the ImageView is not initialized yet, so I cannot setImageBitmap.

Comment: onActivityCreated is called after onCreateView, so dayPhoto object is assigned. I would double check if dayPhoto is not null (actually defined in xml) as well as decodeSampledBitmapFromFile does not return null

Comment: I have checked these. XML - ImageView is defined. Also PhotoUtils... method returns not-null.

Comment: Now I put this setImageBitmap into onStart method, and it still doesn't work, but if I lock the phone, then unlock it I see picture set. I just need the method which will be called before onActivityCreated I guess.

Comment: It works after you dayPhoto object set. Does not matter when you assign image/bitmap. There is something else, may be function does not return not-null object or may be you do something to object dayPhoto (changing parameters, size and etc.). Based on the information you provided it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answers Vladimir, I have found a solution, I will post it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed to use GlobalLayout to make it work :

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                String imgPath = day.getPhotoPath();
                if (imgPath != null) {
                    dayPhoto.setImageBitmap(PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(dayPhoto, imgPath));
                    ViewTreeObserver obs = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
                    obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use new Runnable! Im not sure why, but after hours, by accident, it worked for me! check this out:

```
// Inside onCreateView, or onStart, or even onResume
// super() bla bla bla
// build the Bitmap bmp (restore the path from "savedInstanceState", on wich some point you saved)
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     imgView.setBitmap(bmp, w, h);
  }
});
```